# Return value from helperClass.js not making it back to index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, alexa-skills-kit

**Preface:** I'm new to JavaScript. If this question is startlingly stupid, that's (part of) the reason.

**Begin Update**

I found the answer to my question prior to the flag as a dupe. I solved it with a `try-catch` block. This answer does not reference a `try-catch` block.

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

**End Update**

I'm attempting to create an Alexa project from scratch (well, at least without one of Amazon's templates). I've written the "guts" of the app and I've tested my functions with `chai`. Things were going swimmingly until I tried to wire up some intents.

I can see my intents are being sent based on `console.log` statements I've thrown in the `helperClass`, but the return values aren't making it back to my `index.js` file.

**Two questions:**

1. What am I mucking up?
2. How do I fix it?

**Here's what I've done:**
Based on that, I dug around to see what's going on in my `index.js` file's headers and I saw this:

```
var Alexa = require('alexa-app');
```

So I went to `alexa-app` and saw that it uses `bluebird`, which suggests to me that I'm dealing with a `promise` problem. Further, I saw this in the log when I send a request that works:

```
preRequest fired
postRequest fired
```

When a request doesn't work, I only see:

```
preRequest fired
```

I'm using Big Nerd Ranch's ["Developing Alexa Skills Locally with Node.js"](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/developing-alexa-skills-locally-with-nodejs-implementing-an-intent-with-alexa-app-and-alexa-app-server/).

Here's my problematic `intent` in my `index.js` file:

```
app.intent('getDaysFromNow', {
  'slots': {
        'INPUTDATE' : 'AMAZON.DATE'
  },
    'utterances': ['{|number of|how many} {days} {until|from|since} {|now|today} {|is|was} {-|INPUTDATE}'] // almost perfect
},
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('app.intent getDaysFromNow fired');
    //get the slot
    var inputDate = req.slot('INPUTDATE');
    var reprompt = 'Ask me how many days until or from a specified date.';
    if (_.isEmpty(inputDate)) {
        console.console.log('app.intent daysFromNow blank request');
      var prompt = 'I didn\'t hear the date you want.';
      res.say(prompt).reprompt(reprompt).shouldEndSession(false);
      return true;
    } else {
        console.log('getDaysFromNow slot is not empty.');
      var dateHelper = new DateHelper();
      dateHelper.getDaysFromNow(inputDate).then(function(daysFromNow) { 
        console.log(daysFromNow);
        res.say(dateHelper.formatDaysFromNowResponse(daysFromNow)).send(); // FIXME
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.statusCode);
        var prompt = 'Hmm...I don\'t have a date for that ' + inputDate;
        res.say(prompt).reprompt(reprompt).shouldEndSession(false).send();
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
);
```

I know it's getting sent, but the value's not getting back to `index.js`. I think I've got a return problem. Here's the function in my `helperClass.js` whose return isn't getting back to `index.js`

```
    // Takes AMAZON.DATE string as its argument
DateHelper.prototype.getDaysFromNow = function(inputDate) {

    if (isValidDate(inputDate)) {       // validate it
        // if it's valid, run the function
        inputDate = moment(inputDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").startOf('day'); // inputDate starts as a string, recast as a moment here
        // create currentDate moment from current Date()
        var currentDate = moment(new Date()).startOf('day');

        // Calculate daysFromNow here
        var daysFromNow = inputDate.diff(currentDate, 'days');
        console.log("\t" + 'daysFromNow = ' + daysFromNow);

        // ORIGINAL CODE
        // return daysFromNow;

        // EXPERIMENTAL CODE
        return this.daysFromNow.then(
            function(response) {
                return response.body;
            }
        );
    } else {
        // throw an error
        throw new Error("getDaysFromNow(): argument must be valid AMAZON.DATE string");
    }
};
```

Thank you for reading. I welcome your suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @rohithpr I answered my own question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turns out it's not the way the return is sent from `helperClass`. The issue is how the call was made in the first place.

For the `helperClass`, I reverted to the original return.

```
    // This is the return from `helperClass`
    return daysFromNow;
```

In the `index.js` class, I put the call to `helperClass` in a `try-catch` block, like so:

```
app.intent('getDaysFromNow', {
  'slots': {
    'INPUTDATE': 'AMAZON.DATE'
  },
  'utterances': ['{|number of|how many} {days} {until|from|since} {|now|today} {|is|was} {-|INPUTDATE}'] // almost perfect
},
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('app.intent getDaysFromNow fired');
    //get the slot
    var inputDate = req.slot('INPUTDATE');
    var reprompt = 'Ask me how many days until or from a specified date.';
    if (_.isEmpty(inputDate)) {
      console.log('app.intent daysFromNow blank request');
      var prompt = 'I didn\'t hear the date you want.';
      res.say(prompt).reprompt(reprompt).shouldEndSession(false);
      return true;
    } else {
      // ** CHANGED: This is the part that changed. **
      console.log('getDaysFromNow slot is not empty.');
      var dateHelper = new DateHelper();
      try {
        var daysFromNow = dateHelper.getDaysFromNow(inputDate);
        res.say(dateHelper.formatDaysFromNowResponse(daysFromNow)).send(); 
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        var prompt = 'Hmm...I don\'t have a date for that ' + inputDate;
        res.say(prompt).reprompt(reprompt).shouldEndSession(false).send();
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
);
```

Hopefully, someone finds this helpful if they run into the same problem.